# How Does One Access a Navigation Property on Newly Created Entity

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I am using entity framework 6 code first. I am having a little trouble following what’s going on vis-a-vis navigation properties and foreign keys. Let me elaborate with an example. In this example, I am creating an object and observing what happens with regards to the navigation property when I create an entity that the FK references .

## Entities:

DomainUser {AccountStatus … , UserAccount, UserAccountId} *references UserAccount*

UserAccount { UserAccountId ... }

### 1st Case - Navigation Property is null Upon Creation:

```
var newAccount = userAccountService.CreateAccount(userName, password, email);

var domainUser = new DomainUser
{
    AccountStatus = active,
    UserAccountId = newAccount.ID
};

domainUserRepository.Add(domainUser); // save changes is called on the context in this method.

return domainUser; // at this point, the UserAccount property of domainUser is null
```

### 2nd Case - InvalidOperationExceptionException Thrown

```
var newAccount = userAccountService.CreateAccount(userName, password, email);

var domainUser = new DomainUser
{
    AccountStatus = active,
    UserAccount = newAccount
};

domainUserRepository.Add(domainUser); // "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker."

return domainUser;
```

So my question is, how can I use the navigation property UserAccount?

Do I have to use the UserAccountId to fetch it from the database?

If so, how do I then attach it to the DomainUser object?

I feel like this is something which should have been intuitive. But its not.

Comment: Why does Entity Framework Reinsert Existing Objects into My Database? msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn166926.aspx

Comment: @Colin OK cool. So the 1st case is the way to go. Null because disconnected. Thanks heaps for the reference to that article. Lerman knows her stuff.